# didn't forget to do = remembered to do?

Tags: negation, sentence-meaning

An English grammar book says the following.

> (50) John remembered to mail the letter.
> (= He remembered he had the task and then did it.)

What about the following sentence?

> (60) John didn't forget to mail the letter.

Are (60) and (50) the same or not?

That is, when somebody utters (60), are we sure that John mailed the letter or do we not know about it?

Comment: Please cite a source.

Comment: As you have seen, the *remember-to-do-something* construction, has two components 1) to remember that the task needs doing and 2) to do the task. The *forget-to-do-something* construction also has to components 1) to not remember that the task needs doing and 2) to not do the task. If either of these components is not present then we can say *John did not forget to  mail the letter.* Notice that although (50) is implied by (60), they are not actually equivalent. The reason is that (60) will be true if only one component of the *remember-to-do-something* is missing.

Comment: (cont). So, for example, if John remembered that he should mail the letter, but couldn't be bothered to actually do so, (60) is true, even though he did not post the letter. (50) on the other hand would be false.

Comment: There's a problem with your question in that it jumps to a conclusion. Stating that one "didn't forget" to do something or "remembered" to do something doesn't necessarily mean that that person did it since it's quite possible that they *didn't forget to do it* or *remembered to do it* but nevertheless *didn't do it* for some reason other than forgetting to or not remembering to. One may say, for example, "You said you remembered to make the bed," to which another may respond," I did. I just didn't because I didn't feel like it."

Answer (score 3):

Subtle. Cambridge has

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remember)
> *remember*:
> to not forget to do something

This would seem to answer your question by saying they are equivalent, but as a native speaker I feel a difference.

The difference comes from *remember* being a single action whereas *not forgetting* is a continuous state.

*I remembered to post* implies the single action of posting, whereas *I did not forget to* leaves the outcome more uncertain.

Single action:
*He remembered to sign the will*

Continuous state:
*He did not forget to sign the will, but died before he could do it”.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;-)

Comment: Kind of you. I suggest waiting for others to reply before accepting it. Others may have different views and it would be interesting to hear them.

Comment: I agree with this. To "remember to do something" idiomatically implies you did it. Although there are doubtless some situations where the outcome is in doubt, I'm not sure how far you can go (OK: "John remembered to mail the letter but didn't put the right address on it." Questionable: "John remembered to mail the letter but the post office was on strike.")

Comment: No, it isn't as strong as implication. It's a defeasible implicature (I don't invent these terms; sorry) because you can say (and in fact I've said) things like _I remembered to mail the letter, but then I left it on the shelf by the door_, which implies I forgot again. Us geezers do that a lot and we have speech conventions to cover it.

Comment: In the last example, if you didn't have the clarifying "but..." clause, I would assume he signed the will.